# How can I prove this recurrence equation using mathematical induction?

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations

So for a recurrent equation where $h_n = 2h_{n-1} + h_{n-2}$ with the initial conditions of $h_0 = h_1 = 1$ where $n \geq 2$, prove that $h_n \leq 2.5^n$

I'm suposed to prove this by using mathematical induction and I began by doing the base case where $n = 2$:

$2.5^2 \geq 2h_{2-1} + h_{2-2}$

$2.5^2 \geq 2(1) + 1$

$2.5^2 \geq 3$

which is true for the base case. However, I'm stuck on the inductive hypothesis where I need to prove true for $k+1$ where I have no idea where to begin. I simply made the equation and I'm not sure where to go from there:

$2.5^{k+1} \geq 2h_{k} + h_{k-1}$

There are subscripts and superscripts on both sides of the equation and mathematical induction problems do not have those scenarios.

Comment: The two base cases are given. You just need to prove the induction step.

Comment: Just use what you know about $h_k$ and $h_{k-1}$ (your induction hypothesis).

Comment: is this $$2\cdot5^n$$ or $$2.5^n$$

Comment: it's supposed to be $2.5^n$

Comment: $$h_{n+1}=2h_n+h_{n-1}\leq 2\times 2.5^n+2.5^{n-1}=2.5^{n-1}(2\times 2.5+1)=2.5^{n-1}\times 6\leq 2.5^{n+1}$$ since $6\leq 6.25=(2.5)^2$

Comment: You need to use strong induction rather than the usual form: to show the proposition for $n+1$, assume it to be true for both $n$ and $n-1$ (as such you need two base cases: $h_0=(2.5)^0=1$ and $h_1=1\leq 2.5=(2.5)^1$ does the job)

Answer (score 1):

You have to prove that $$h_{n+1}\le 2.5^n$$ now we have given
$$h_{n+1}=2h_n+h_{n-1}$$ now using that
$$h_n\le 2.5^n$$ and $$h_{n-1}\le 2.5^{n-1}$$ so we get
$$h_{n+1}\le 2\cdot 2.5^n+2.5^{n-1}$$
Can you finish?
This is $$2.5^{n-1}(5+1)=6\cdot 2.5^{n-1}\le 2.5^{n+1}$$ since $$6\le 2.5^2$$

Comment: Yeah I got it, what you did was substitute $2.5^{k+1}$ into $h_{n+1}$. Then the trick was to divide both sides by 2.5 to get rid of the $n-1$ exponent. Then you factored out $2.5^k$ and the constant arithmetic ends up being 6. Then you divided by $2.5^k$ again on both sides to get $2.5^2 \geq 6$